# Setting DataContext in XAML in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have following code:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding Employee}">
    <Grid>       
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="ID:"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Name:"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" Text="{Binding EmpID}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" Text="{Binding EmpName}" /> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Employee.cs**

```
namespace SampleApplication
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            EmployeeDetails employeeDetails = new EmployeeDetails();
            employeeDetails.EmpID = 123;
            employeeDetails.EmpName = "ABC";
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeDetails
    {
        private int empID;
        public int EmpID
        {
            get
            {
                return empID;
            }
            set
            {
                empID = value;
            }
        }

        private string empName;
        public string EmpName
        {
            get
            {
                return empName;
            }
            set
            {
                empName = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is very simple code and I just want to bind the `EmpID` and `EmpName` properties in my Employee.cs class to Text properties of Textboxes in MainWindow.xaml but nothing is appearing in my these textboxes when I am running the code. Is the binding right?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

This code will always fail.

As written, it says: "Look for a property named "Employee" on my DataContext property, and set it to the DataContext property". Clearly that isn't right.

To get your code to work, as is, change your window declaration to:

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApplication"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:Employee/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

This declares a new XAML namespace (local) and sets the DataContext to an instance of the Employee class. This will cause your bindings to display the default data (from your constructor).

However, it is highly unlikely this is actually what you want. Instead, you should have a new class (call it MainViewModel) with an `Employee` property that you then bind to, like this:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
   public Employee MyEmployee { get; set; } //In reality this should utilize INotifyPropertyChanged!
}
```

Now your XAML becomes:

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApplication"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
       <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    ...
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" Text="{Binding MyEmployee.EmpID}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" Text="{Binding MyEmployee.EmpName}" />
```

Now you can add other properties (of other types, names), etc. For more information, see [Implementing the Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx)

Comment: Even now textbox is not populated.

Comment: @nkp, have you checked for System.Data exceptions? They should guide you to any typos.

Comment: I have not yet successfully bound to the view model in XAML without adding the assembly. Just stating for awareness.
`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApplication;assembly=SampleApplication"`

Comment: @MistaGoustan Yes, you *always* need to use an XMLNS to reference your view model type

Comment: My project was on a shared folder and it was giving a similar error

Comment: It should be noted that the DataContext is only set _after_ the call to `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor of the window class (code behind). Just in case anyone has some initialization code that depends on the data context to be set.

Answer (score 27):

First of all you should create property with employee details in the `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        EmployeeDetails = new EmployeeDetails();
        EmployeeDetails.EmpID = 123;
        EmployeeDetails.EmpName = "ABC";
    }

    public EmployeeDetails EmployeeDetails { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't do that, you will create instance of object in `Employee` constructor and you lose reference to it.

In the XAML you should create instance of `Employee` class, and after that you can assign it to `DataContext`.

Your XAML should look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApplication"
   >
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Employee x:Key="Employee" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource Employee}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="ID:"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Name:"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" Text="{Binding EmployeeDetails.EmpID}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" Text="{Binding EmployeeDetails.EmpName}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, after you created property with employee details you should binding by using this property:

```
Text="{Binding EmployeeDetails.EmpID}"
```

Answer (score 10):

There are several issues here.

1. You can't assign DataContext as `DataContext="{Binding Employee}"` because it's a complex object which can't be assigned as string. So you have to use `<Window.DataContext></Window.DataContext>` syntax.
2. You assign the class that represents the data context object to the view, not an individual property so `{Binding Employee}` is invalid here, you just have to specify an object.
3. Now when you assign data context using valid syntax like below

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:Employee/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

know that you are *creating* a new instance of the Employee class and assigning it as the data context object. You may well have nothing in default constructor so nothing will show up. But then how do you manage it in code behind file? You have typecast the DataContext.

```
private void my_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Employee e = (Employee) DataContext;
}
```

4. A second way is to assign the data context in the code behind file itself. The advantage then is your code behind file already knows it and can work with it.

   ```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
            DataContext = employee;
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: one major problem i face with setting "dataContext" in the code Behind , is that now "ICommand" become not working along side with other events , and im using a Window. not a viewModel . any way to solve this ?

Comment: Swap the two lines in the constructor i.e. put the 'InitializeComponent();' in the end, that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It probably could work, just if you change

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{Binding Employee}">
```

to

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.Employee">
```

(Thanks to *BradleyDotNET* above for noticing the Binding source issue.)
I know that it's also probably not the best answer, but I think that it's important to add (i.e. when you want to add 'child view' to your view and you want to assign as its DataContext the object from 'parent view'.)