# MVVM does not load view dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I wrote a wpf application that should load view dynamically, depends on condition.The XAML looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="Backup.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Backup.Views"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Backup.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        Height="300"
        Width="300"
        Title="Backup V1.0"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStyle="None"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DeniedViewModel}">
            <views:DeniedView />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CopyViewModel}">
            <views:CopyView />
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentVm}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the view model

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Backup.Model;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using Libraries.Extension;
using Libraries.Interfaces;

namespace Backup.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     This class contains properties that the main View can data bind to.
    ///     <para>
    ///         See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly ViewModelLocator _locator;
        //private readonly IDataService _dataService;
        private readonly IPermissionService _permission;
        private readonly IPersistence _persistence;
        private ViewModelBase _currentVm;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel(IPermissionService permission, IPersistence persistence)
        {

            if (_GetOSInfo() != "7")
            {
                Application.Current.Shutdown();
                return;
            }

            _permission = permission;
            _persistence = persistence;
            _locator = (ViewModelLocator) Application.Current.TryFindResource("Locator");

            CurrentVm = _locator.DeniedVm;


            //Validate if the user is in ad group
            //_persistence.QueryGroups((groups, err) =>
            //{
            //    if (!_permission.Check(groups))
            //    {
            //        CurrentVm = _locator.DeniedVm;
            //        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
            //        {
            //            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            //            Application.Current.Shutdown();
            //        }));
            //        return;
            //    }

            //    CurrentVm = _locator.CopyVm;
            //});
        }

        public ViewModelBase CurrentVm
        {
            get { return _currentVm; }
            set
            {
                _currentVm = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetPropertyName());
            }
        }

        private string _GetOSInfo()
        {
            //Get Operating system information.
            var os = Environment.OSVersion;
            //Get version information about the os.
            var vs = os.Version;

            //Variable to hold our return value
            var operatingSystem = "";

            if (os.Platform == PlatformID.Win32Windows)
            {
                //This is a pre-NT version of Windows
                switch (vs.Minor)
                {
                    case 0:
                        operatingSystem = "95";
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        if (vs.Revision.ToString() == "2222A")
                            operatingSystem = "98SE";
                        else
                            operatingSystem = "98";
                        break;
                    case 90:
                        operatingSystem = "Me";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if (os.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
            {
                switch (vs.Major)
                {
                    case 3:
                        operatingSystem = "NT 3.51";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        operatingSystem = "NT 4.0";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if (vs.Minor == 0)
                            operatingSystem = "2000";
                        else
                            operatingSystem = "XP";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        if (vs.Minor == 0)
                            operatingSystem = "Vista";
                        else
                            operatingSystem = "7";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return operatingSystem;
        }
    }
}
```

When I executed the application on my computer, everything works fine, but on other computer it shows only blank wpf surface.
I suspect, that the view is not loading correctly, maybe contentcontrol does not load the view.
What am I doing wrong?

### **Update**

I analysed wpf with snoop following error occurs:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Main' value (type 'MainViewModel') from '' (type 'ViewModelLocator'). BindingExpression:Path=Main; DataItem='ViewModelLocator' (HashCode=39201736); target element is 'MainWindow' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
```

What should I do?

Comment: Swallowing exceptions?  If you have access to this other machine, throw Snoop on it.  Browse the visual tree and look at the binding.  It'll tell you what the issue is.

Comment: I think the DataContext is not set proper. please check this 
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" .

Comment: @AbinMathew how to bind datacontext then correctly

Comment: Check this link: the error in the edit says that its related to DataContext:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713898/setting-datacontext-in-xaml-in-wpf

Comment: You need a property called Main in your ViewModelLocator