# WPF INotifyPropertyChanged not updating label

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I'm currently learning some basics in WPF and I've been looking for the mistake for about 2 days. Hope you guys can help.

I'm trying to update my UI (in this case the content of a label) by using INotifyPropertyChanged and a binding in XAML. The thing is: it only takes the first value and puts it in the content. Furthermore nothing happens but the event (OnPropertyChanged) is fired.

This is what I have in XAML:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" x:Class="MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:View x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,-4" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
....
    <Label x:Name="lbl_money" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{Binding Path=PropMoney}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="403,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

And this is the necessary part of my class View:

```
Public Class View
Inherits ViewModelBase

Private rest1 As New Restaurant
Private mainPlayer As New Player
Private mycurrentMoney As Double = 3
Private currentClickIncrease = mainPlayer.PropClickIncrease

 Public Property PropMoney() As Double
    Get
        Return mycurrentMoney
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        mycurrentMoney = value
        OnPropertyChanged("mycurrentMoney")
    End Set
End Property

Sub SelfClicked()
    PropMoney() += 1
End Sub
```

Last but not least the MainWindow class, where i instantiate my view:

```
Class MainWindow

Private view As New View

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        view.SelfClicked()
    End Sub

End Class
```

So my *mycurrentMoney* is increasing each click and the event is fired but the label doesn't update.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use `OnPropertyChanged("PropMoney")` instead

Comment: I did but unfortunately no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code

First you raise `PropertyChanged` event for the backing field and should raise it for property name

```
OnPropertyChanged("PropMoney")
```

Second the property you change belong to different instance of `View` then the one set as `DataContext`. So in XAML remove `DataContext` changes, only leave property binding

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,-4">
        <!-- .... -->
        <Label ... Content="{Binding Path=PropMoney}">
```

and then in code set `DataContext` of `MainWindow` to the instance that you create and modify

```
Class MainWindow

Private view As New View

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        DataContext = view
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        view.SelfClicked()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `OnPropertyChanged("mycurrentMoney")` statement won't raise a property change on your property, because it's called *PropMoney*.

You have to set `OnPropertyChanged("PropMoney")` in your setter instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Visual Studio 15 use NameOf operator instead of string literal like so:

```
NameOf(PropMoney);
```

If you later rename your property, it will still work opposed to string literal which will NOT. Alternatively modify your OnPropertyChange to make use of `CallerMemberName`

```
OnPropertyChange ([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{

}
```

The property name will be filled in, this works only in setter for current property however.

Also, set DataContext for whole window ([Setting DataContext in XAML in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713898/setting-datacontext-in-xaml-in-wpf)). `DataContext={StaticResource ViewModel}` and don't use Path in your Binding, just `{Binding PropertyName}`

Comment: Where do i have to insert/replace the NameOf(PropMoney)?

Comment: Instead of ""PropMoney"" in your OnPropertyChange method call.