# How do i set the data context in XAML to global static variable?

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my App.xaml.cs I have a global view model

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
}
```

and I've always set data context in the code behind like this

```
public MainWindow(){
  ...
  DataContext = App.viewModel;
  ...
}
```

However I want to try doing the same thing but in the XAML.  How do I select the class and static property from the XAML?
So far I have in my UserControl

```
<UserControl ...
         xmlns:global="clr-namespace:MyMainNamespace"
```

(App would be under that namespace like this  MyMainNamespace.App)

and then I can select 'App' just fine from global like this

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <global:App x:Key="test"></global:App>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.DataContext>
   ??
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

And further down in the user control I have a combo box that I want to bind to an observable collection inside the viewModel

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Width="150" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ></ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

**Edit:** I was trying to model my solution after this answer 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/23714054/1462656

But I could not find a way to select the viewModel object from App without it giving me syntax errors

Comment: <UserControl DataContext="{x:Static global:App.viewModel}"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to your resource using a `StaticResource` binding for the `Source`, and grab a property off of it using the binding's `Path`, like this:

```
<UserControl ...Existing attributes... DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource test},
                                                             Path=viewModel}">
```

---

If you *really* want the `DataContext` in the "attached" format, you could do it like this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="viewmodel" Source="{StaticResource test}" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

...but you will have to make `viewModel` an actual property, it won't work as a field.  Your code may also generate an `InvalidOperationException`

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot create more than one
>   System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.

if `App` is your application class generated from `App.xaml.cs`, as the format you use to declare the resource will create a new instance of it.  This will happen even with the "inline" syntax above.  It isn't caused by the binding, but by the resource declaration.

---

My *preferred* way of doing this, would be to just create a view-model class for the control that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, let's just call it `MyControlVm` for this example.  Then set the `DataContext` like this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local: MyControlVm />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

This would allow you to have multiple instance of your `UserControl` without them all sharing the same state (as your `static` property of `App` would).

Comment: For me, test is pointing to the App class, but how do set the dataContext to the viewModel property inside App (not to the entire App class)?

Comment: Sorry about that, I misread your code.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: ok,what about in the style I wrote above - inside <UserControl.DataContext> tag

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it's possible to do it that way, I've never tried.  Is there any special reason you want it in that format?  The result should be identical.

Comment: I suppose I was just trying to learn different ways to set the data context  in my app.  That's ok if its not possible or necessary.

Comment: I figured out the binding, but I think you will run in to another problem.  The way you declare the resource `App` will cause it to create a new instance of `App`, which I believe is your application class created from `App.xaml.cs`. This isn't allowed, and you will get the exception "InvalidOperationException: Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain."

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Your right, the first way works fine, but the second way causes an error, although my error was different type - "The invocation of the constructor on type 'MyMainNamespace.App' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception"  Regardless, I'll try and implement the third suggestion eventually, everyone I've shown this to suggested the same thing.  .